# glXCreateContextAttribsARB not found (on OpenGL 4.2 driver, GLX 1.4)

Tags: c, linux, drivers, xserver, glx

Strangely enough, despite the fact that I have GLX 1.4, it appears that I don't have `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` in my repos.

I wonder if there's any reasonable explanation for this? This can't be a common issue.

**glxinfo**

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
    GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_NV_video_out, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_NV_present_video, GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, 
    GLX_NV_video_capture, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 290.10
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_bindable_uniform, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader, GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, GL_EXT_direct_state_access, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_storage, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, 
    GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback2, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, 
    GL_EXT_x11_sync_object, GL_EXT_import_sync_object, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_alpha_test, 
    GL_NV_blend_minmax, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_complex_primitives, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_depth_buffer_float, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_explicit_multisample, 
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_fence, GL_NV_float_buffer, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_fragdepth, GL_NV_fragment_program, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_fragment_program2, 
    GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage, GL_NV_geometry_shader4, 
    GL_NV_gpu_program4, GL_NV_gpu_program4_1, GL_NV_gpu_program5, 
    GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64, GL_NV_gpu_shader5, GL_NV_half_float, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_multisample_coverage, 
    GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint, GL_NV_occlusion_query, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_register_combiners, GL_NV_register_combiners2, 
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters, GL_NV_shader_buffer_load, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_NV_texture_expand_normal, GL_NV_texture_lod_clamp, 
    GL_NV_texture_multisample, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_texture_shader, 
    GL_NV_texture_shader2, GL_NV_texture_shader3, GL_NV_transform_feedback, 
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, GL_NV_vertex_array_range, 
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2, GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit, 
    GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_NV_vertex_program2, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option, GL_NV_vertex_program3, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_OES_depth24, 
    GL_OES_depth32, GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, 
    GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_depth_texture, 
    GL_SGIX_shadow, GL_SUN_slice_accum
```

Obviously buffer binding, `ARB`, and all that other nice stuff is supported, but why not `glXCreateContextAttribsARB`?

Even stranger, what I *do* have is `glXCreateContextAttribsARBPRoc`, which I'm curious to know if it would serve as an alternative?

This compiles, for example:

```
`glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glxccarb = 0;`
```

Answer (score 4):

When you say "don't have", I assume you mean "if I try to call a function of this name directly, my app won't link".

That's somewhat by design.  The list of functions directly exported from libGL is not growing.  If it did, an app that links against a (function exported only by a) new libGL would fail to even launch against an old one.  That's bad.

`glXCreateContextAttribsARB`, like all other extension functions, should be looked up using `glXGetProcAddressARB`.  Better yet, use [GLEW](http://glew.sf.net/) so you don't have to worry about this level of detail again.

Comment: Do'h! This seems so obvious now! Thanks for this. It's been messing my head for a while now